# Clickable button in custom Spinner item blocks clicking of item itself

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have custom `ArrayAdapter` and custom item layout for `Spinner`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/delete"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:background="?attr/transparentRoundRipple"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_grey600_24px" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this layout there is a button that deletes this item

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_user_agent_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    textView.setText(getItem(position));

    ImageButton deleteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> removeAgent(getItem(position)));

    return view;
}
```

But the problem is that the listener of this button blocks the click of the element itself and I cannot select it from the list. Is it possible to change the behavior and make it so that I can click on the button (for deletion) and on the element itself (for selection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple: use `ImageView` instead of `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your `android:clickable="true"` in `RelativeLayout` also `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`